# How to animate to a specific position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've searched high and low and cannot seem to find a solution.

I want to be able to click on a div and have it animate to specific location (say, x:200 y:200) regardless of where it already lives on the page. For example, if I have 4 divs scattered on my page, I want to be able to have them animate to a unified coordinate. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? It would be very much appreciated. I've tried various tricks using .position and .offset but none seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). look at this example:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({top: '50px', left: '50px'}, 2000, function () {
    console.log('done!');
});
```

it will animate the div with id "myDiv" to (50,50) over a period of 2 seconds.